# Up-to-date OAuth 1a PHP implementation

Tags: library, php

I want to create a PHP OAuth server with version 1a.
But the problem with OAuth is: it isn't actually an application, it's a specification.
So you have to go out there and find which implementation of OAuth you want.
Is there a certified OAuth PHP implementation?
I am skeptical of just choosing a random library for it.

For example: [this library](https://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/) seems nice, until you realize the developers haven't released an update since November 2010, and that it has over 50 issues.

So, is there an up-to-date library that

- hasn't been abandoned;
- is OAuth certified?

NOTE: I know OAuth 2 exists, but I prefer OAuth 1a and the way it works after reading [this](http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/26/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/).

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401026/is-there-an-omniauth-for-php

Answer (score 1):

Both oAuth 1.0a and 2.0 are being used by many sites. Most sites that use oAuth 2.0 use also SSL to prevent security breaches. oAuth 1.0a can also be used but it is usually more complicated because it requires a complex request signature procedure.

If you are looking for a [PHP oAuth client library](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html) being actively maintained, you can use the PHP oAuth API class. It supports either oAuth 1.0, 1.0a and 2.0, along many other non-trivial oAuth specification features, like refresh tokens, 2-legged authentication, client password authentication, etc..