# Recommendation about PHP OAuth plugins

Tags: php, authentication

I would like to find an OAuth plugin for vanilla PHP that is easy to use and well documented with examples. I have spent several days reading tutorials and articles as well as trying to implement OAuth from several parties. I have tried opauth, googles PHP oauth and f3 opauth plugin. They are all buggy and/or poorly documented.

This [SO question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/up-to-date-oauth-1a-php-implementation) is outdated. It does point to a promising site, but trying to registering there wore my patience thin.

Comment: Could you expand on how much documentation is needed and why the other above mentioned libraries were buggy?

Comment: opauth has sketchy documentaion and the sample they provide is incomplete. I spent many hours trying to get it to work and finally gave up. Google PHP oauth got me pretty far, but kept throwing a JSON error that did not make any sense, <a href="https://github.com/ikkez/f3-opauth"> f3 auth's documentation</a> is not useful for a novice PHP deveoper.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/), just month ago updates. As for easy to use, in their homepage there is an example of "connect to Twitter, update your status and grab your friends list in 20 lines of code". About documentation, they have a pretty complete user-guide.

Answer (score 0):

Just last week I've been to a [talk](https://www.codetalks.de/de/2017/programm/protect-your-api-with-oauth2) at a developer conference.

The speaker recommended https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/. The github repo was downloaded > 2 million times in 2017.

I haven't used it before, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard nowadays is https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client

It has plenty examples, a lot of documentation, is compatible with most of the PHP versions, and follows the PSR standards.